# Can you use a Confusion Matrix for a image detection problem?

Tags: object-detection, image-recognition, confusion-matrix

I have read the classic examples of using a Confusion Matrix for a classification problem. ("Does a patient have cancer, or not?)

The ML system I am working with is for detecting objects in an image. (To be precise, it is more than that, it detects object's directions, postures, etc)

My question is, can a Confusion Matrix be used with this kind of problems?

Comment: If you can put the predictions into a table then yes, maybe. It really depends how you want to measure this. If however your output is numerical in nature and you would have to discretize the output to estimate the classifcation, then reconsdier.

Comment: Yes, if you have well defined classes in each case and you want to evalauate how well your model performed one each class. Please refer to this link : https://www.kdnuggets.com/2021/03/evaluating-object-detection-models-using-mean-average-precision.html for more details